# Angular js - How to do strict and progressive search on same field?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do strict and progressive search on same fields in 2 different ways. That is when filter through drop down it should to a strict search and through input search it should do a progressive search. I tried to do it using `<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:{name:name||dropdownFieldName:true, country:country}">` but is giving some error, Its not working.
Please check the bellow code and help me to solve this issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<select id="fieldDropdownHtml" ng-model="fieldSelected" ng-options="x.name for x in names" ng-change="searchOnField()">
<option  value=""></option>
</select>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-disabled="disablese"></p>
<td><p><input type="text" ng-model="country"></p>

</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:{name:name||dropdownFieldName, country:country}">
<!--tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:{name:name||dropdownFieldName:true, country:country}" -->

<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.country}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.disablese = false;
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Jani1',country:'England'},
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'}
        ];

 $scope.searchOnField = function() {
            var e = document.getElementById("fieldDropdownHtml");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

            angular.forEach($scope.names, function(dsElement) {
                if (dsElement.name === strUser) {
                    $scope.dropdownFieldName = dsElement.name;
                    console.log($scope.dropdownFieldName);
                }

            if(document.getElementById('fieldDropdownHtml').selectedIndex == 0){
                $scope.dropdownFieldName= undefined;
            }
             if(document.getElementById('fieldDropdownHtml').selectedIndex != 0){
                $scope.disablese = true;
                $scope.name = "";

            } 
            else{
                            $scope.disablese = false;

            }
            });

    } 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by separating filters like below.

```
ng-repeat="x in names | filter:{name:name||dropdownFieldName}: disablese | filter: { country:country }"
```

Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<select id="fieldDropdownHtml" ng-model="fieldSelected" ng-options="x.name for x in names" ng-change="searchOnField()">
<option  value=""></option>
</select>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-disabled="disablese"></p>
<td><p><input type="text" ng-model="country"></p>

</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:{name:name||dropdownFieldName}: disablese | filter: { country:country }">
<!--tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:{name:name||dropdownFieldName:true, country:country}" -->

<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.country}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.disablese = false;
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Jani1',country:'England'},
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Jani',country:'Harway'}
        ];

 $scope.searchOnField = function() {
            var e = document.getElementById("fieldDropdownHtml");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

            angular.forEach($scope.names, function(dsElement) {
                if (dsElement.name === strUser) {
                    $scope.dropdownFieldName = dsElement.name;
                    console.log($scope.dropdownFieldName);
                }

            if(document.getElementById('fieldDropdownHtml').selectedIndex == 0){
                $scope.dropdownFieldName= undefined;
            }
             if(document.getElementById('fieldDropdownHtml').selectedIndex != 0){
                $scope.disablese = true;
                $scope.name = "";

            } 
            else{
                            $scope.disablese = false;

            }
            });

    } 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to [Allabakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7561063/allabakash) answer, you can use this code to your controller to make it simpler and minimize vanilla JavaScript codes:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('namesCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.disablese = false;
        $scope.names = [
            { name: 'Jani', country: 'Norway' },
            { name: 'Carl', country: 'Sweden' },
            { name: 'Margareth', country: 'England' },
            { name: 'Hege', country: 'Norway' },
            { name: 'Joe', country: 'Denmark' },
            { name: 'Gustav', country: 'Sweden' },
            { name: 'Birgit', country: 'Denmark' },
            { name: 'Jani1', country: 'England' },
            { name: 'Jani', country: 'Norway' }
        ];

        $scope.searchOnField = function () {
            if ($scope.fieldSelected) {
                $scope.dropdownFieldName = $scope.fieldSelected.name;
                $scope.name = null;
                $scope.disablese = true;
            } else {
                $scope.dropdownFieldName = undefined;
                $scope.disablese = false;
            }
        };
    });
```